# Why all attributes are prefixed?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

What is the design advantage to do this

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="105px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
```

and not this

```
<android:TextView
    layout_width="105px"
    layout_height="wrap_content"
    text="@string/hello"
    />
```

Is that android: prefix everywhere not a little bit to chatty?

Comment: I'm not really strong on xml syntax but I think it's the namespace of the attribute.

Comment: No, it's the prefix bound to a namespace (the binding has a specific scope and it is always local to an XML document). The prefix is used in XML documents to put elements and sometimes attributes in a namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android` is a namespace prefix and it is used to tell that those attributes are in the XML namespace bound to that prefix. You should have a namespace declaration somewhere in your XML document which looks like `xmlns:android = "the namespace URI here"`. It is quite unusual to prefix attributes but it is necessary when attributes of a given XML vocabulary are found in XML elements not belonging to that vocabulary because it avoids collisions.

Answer (score 1):

In XML, attributes have to be prefixed in order to be in a namespace; they don't automatically pick up the namespace of the element.

Comment: Indeed, but usually having the attributes in a precise element, itself in a namespace, is enough to know what the attributes are, what they mean. It is not the case when the attributes are included in elements belonging to different XML vocabularies.

Answer (score 0):

Its xml references afaik, look at the top view and see the link.

Comment: What do you mean by "xml references" ?

Comment: Quick answer from phone ;) I meant the same as the guy who answered this question :)

Answer (score 0):

Have never seen the second variant in use and don't really know if it works or not. If yes - I'm sure you can use it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is: there is no advantage in this design. Which is why I've never seen anyone use it.